# reinstalling application problem in android

Tags: java, android

I try to use reinstall a application that I made in android. but, istalliation doesnt complete, it s not installed. after I uninstall application that in device, than, I try again to install same application. in this time, it s intalled.

what may be to block reinstalling a application ?

Comment: do you get any message in console or logcat?

Comment: So this happens every time you try to reinstall it? As a side-note: you have to manually uninstall and reinstall an app when you run it from different computers.

Comment: Of course, if the device is at level 1.6, and the manifest is changed to require 2.1+, then the application won't update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it s about signature problem. after I look detail, even application is same, but their signature is different. so, overrite is not finished. the signatures must be same, if you update a program.